# Batch: Fill array by text file with escaped characters

Tags: html, arrays, batch-file, utf-8, escaping

I've got two arrays to fill from a text file. One with UTF-8 umlauts and one with escaped.

```
all_headings_html_umlauts_escaped.txt
^&Uuml^;berblick
^&Auml^;pfel
^&Ouml^;sterreich

all_headings_utf8_umlauts.txt
Überblick
Äpfel
Österreich
```

My batch file:

```
@echo off
:: Build array to iterate through
set /A n=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("all_headings_utf8_umlauts.txt") do (
    set /A n+=1
REM call echo %%n%%
    call set arrayutfeight[%%n%%]=%%a
    call set o=%%n%%
)


for /L %%i in (1,1,%o%) do call echo %%arrayutfeight[%%i]%%
pause

:: Build arrayy to iterate through
set /A p=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("all_headings_html_umlauts_escaped.txt") do (
    set /A p+=1
REM call echo %%k%%
    call set arrayhtmlescaped[%%p%%]=%%b
    call set q=%%p%%
)


for /L %%i in (1,1,%q%) do call echo %%arrayhtmlescaped[%%i]%%
pause
```

The ouput of the first array works perfectly and as it should be but the ouput of the second one is three times "ECHO is off".
Any ideas why and how I can solve this issue? I really need as an output in my batch file from the array ^&Uuml^;berblick...

KR
Mark

Answer (score 0):

The management of the `^` caret character is complicated in a Batch file. Such a character is duplicated when it appears in a line in certain cases. In this way, the `call set "arrayhtmlescaped[%%p%%]=%%b"` line stores *two* carets per each one in the file, so extra carets must be removed. The simplest way to do that is using Delayed Expansion, but in the `echo` command the carets are placed *outside quotes*, so it is necessary to *escape each caret* with an additional one.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Build arrayy to iterate through
set /A p=0
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%b in ("all_headings_html_umlauts_escaped.txt") do (
    set /A p+=1
REM call echo %%k%%
    call set "arrayhtmlescaped[%%p%%]=%%b"
    call set q=%%p%%
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%q%) do echo !arrayhtmlescaped[%%i]:^^^^=^^!
pause
```